# Spark Structured Streaming read different event types from kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a kafka topic with several event types.

My events value look like:

```
type|name|value1|value2|value3
type|name|value1|value2|value3|value4
type|name|value1|value2
```

I used structured streaming to readstream kafka. I want to store stream data to dataframe. The result dataframe has schema which is including columns in all schemas.
Can I store event records of each type in a dataframe then select from these dataframes  and union them in order to result dataframe ?